# Find sum of alternating series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {(-1)^{n+1}} {n^2}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find sum of series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {(-1)^{n+1}} {n^2}$$.

I know the series converge absolutely so it is clearly convergent and in the absolute case the sum is $\pi^2/6$. However, I can't seem to find the sum in this case ?

Also the series is alternating.

Can someone help me out ?

Comment: First find $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1/(2n)^2$.

Comment: This is a special case of the [Dirichlet Eta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function) or alternating Zeta function, and you find $\eta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}{12}$ in the particular value section.

Comment: So it is not a series you just compute "easily" ?

Answer (score 11):

It is well known that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ and so
$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2n)^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{24}$
Thus
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^2}=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}-2\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2n)^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}-2\frac{\pi^2}{24}=
\frac{\pi^2}{12}$$

Comment: This is similar in spirit to the fact that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2n+1)^{2}} = \frac{\pi^{2}}{6} - \frac{\pi^{2}}{24} = \frac{\pi^{2}}{8}.$

Comment: Why does the first well known series imply the other ? Ohh, I see we get a factor of $1/4$ in the partial series..

Comment: How did you get to $\frac1{n^2}-2$?

Comment: He subtract one sum from two times the other sum (both convergent).

Answer (score 3):

Even if it is a little backwards engineering, I think one natural way to compute it is to compute the Fourier-Series of
$$
f(x):=-\frac{1}{4}x^2+\frac{\pi^2}{12}\qquad -\pi<x<\pi
$$
The convergence of the series to the function (pointwise is already enough) gives the desired result when evaluating at $x=0$.

EDIT: Rene's answer is much nicer! (Altough it uses the fact that $\sum_n n^{-2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ which is usually also proved with the help of Fourier-Series).

Comment: there is a visual proof for $\sum_n n^{-2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ :http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1044022/are-there-any-visual-proofs-for-sum-n-1-infty-frac1n2-frac-pi2/1281530#1281530