# What is the rationale behind the famous pi formula of Ramanujan

Tags: pi

Every times I look at this formula I get astonished:
$$\frac{1}{\pi} = \frac{2 \sqrt 2}{99^2} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(4k)!}{k!^4} \frac{26390k+1103}{396^{4k}}.$$

Can someone give me an idea of the reasoning behind that formula?

Comment: it doesn't look easy, [see there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14115/motivation-for-ramanujans-mysterious-pi-formula) and [there](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%E2%80%93Sato_series)

Comment: There are *proofs* of that formula, as linked above and elsewhere. But as far as I know Ramanujan never gave a hint of how *he* found it himself.