# Are there any geometric proofs for these series relating to pi?

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometry, alternative-proof, pi

**Edit:** I saw that Math.SE question and talked/linked it in my last paragraph as well as in the comments.

Here are two series for $\pi^2$

$$\frac{\pi^2}{6} = 1 + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{9} + \frac{1}{25} + \frac{1}{36} ... $$

$$\frac{\pi^2}{8} = 1 + \frac{1}{9} + \frac{1}{25} + \frac{1}{49} + \frac{1}{81}...$$

These are **the simplest and easiest** series for pi that I know. They're all positive terms, they're all simple fractions of squares.

What I'd like to know is, can either of those two series be proved purely geometrically? Preferably involving only squares and circles.

I have seen a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WBW32VvQr6E&t=360s) proving the first one using polynomials and trig series. I also saw another [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MqtqY5-atuo) proving a related (but still simple) series using an integral and the arctan function. None of them were very geometric.

It seems tantalizing because the series **only involves fractions of squares** (numerical squaring), so you'd hope there was some proof involving squares (the shape). For reference, $c^2 = a^2 + b^2$ has a [purely geometrical proof](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r382kfkqAF4) by rearranging triangles into 2 squares (a square with a square hole in the middle), and then just a little algebra.

Btw, I'm aware that **"squaring the circle" is impossible.** I'm not trying to do that. I'm not trying to construct (with compass and straightedge) a square whose area is equal to a circle. I could easily draw a square, label the sides with $\sqrt{\pi}$ or $\pi$, and then **prove the area** is $\pi$ or $\pi^2$, not using compass nor straightedge. I could just as easily draw a circle, label its circumference as 1, then draw a bounding square and **prove its area** is $\frac{1}{\pi^2}$.

What I'm **actually trying to do** is show that a unit square plus one quarter of it plus one ninth of it, etc, is somehow equal to a one sixth of a square whose side length is $\pi$. I suppose this could be done by involving a circle of unit diameter, or a circle of unit circumference whose diameter is therefore 1/pi.

Alternatively, I'm trying to show that a unit square plus one ninth of it plus one twenty-fifth of it, etc, is somehow equal to one eighth of a square whose side length is pi.

Using triangles is okay too but preferably without having to use the trig functions or their infinite series. Hopefully there will be a way to use area of a triangle (bh/2) to get to squares.

I've also looked at [Basel's Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem) and the last proof which is **claimed** to be "the most elementary", but it involves binomial theorem and vieta's formula and furthermore does not seem to involve any squares (the shape).

I've also seen [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1044022/are-there-any-visual-proofs-for-sum-n-1-infty-frac1n2-frac-pi2) on Math.SE, but the first answer has a dead link and the pictures seem to involve a stack of squares and some curved line **related to e, not pi and not a circle.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are there any visual proofs for $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1044022/are-there-any-visual-proofs-for-sum-n-1-infty-frac1n2-frac-pi2)

Comment: @ElementsinSpace Yea I saw it and linked to it. I did not see any proofs there involving only circles, squares, and triangles. Also, that question is only about the first series, but I would be happy with a geo proof for the $\frac{\pi^2}{8}$ series too.

Comment: I'd say that the first step would be to find a geometric interpretation of $\pi^2$.

Comment: @Qudit A square whose side-lengths are pi is one interpretation. See my paragraph below $c^2 = a^2 + b^2$.

Comment: @DrZ214 That's hardly a natural one that's likely to be useful.

Comment: @ElementsinSpace Well no, circle area = $\pi r^2$. So it's pi*1*1 = pi. The pi is not squared.